# Replace a pattern in column of a csv file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I am looking for some help with editing CSV in python. I have a file in below format

| Account | InstanceId | InstanceName | InstanceType | Platform | Status | AvailabilityZone | PrivateIpAddress | publicIpAdress | Owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678901 | i-0abcdef1234567890 | Test123 | t3a.micro | windows | stopped | ap-southeast-2a | 10.0.0.100 |  | arn:aws:sts::12345678901:user/test-user |
| 98765432109 | i-0987654321abcdefg | test345 | t2.nano | Linux | running | ap-southeast-2b | 10.0.0.200 | 99.99.99.100 | arn:aws:sts::98765432109:assumed-role/testrole/user@example.com |
| 98765432109 | i-abcdefghij01234899 | test987 | t2.nano | windows | running | ap-southeast-2b | 10.0.0.201 |  |  |

I would like to edit this file in place and and have the resulting file in below format

| Account | InstanceId | InstanceName | InstanceType | Platform | Status | AvailabilityZone | PrivateIpAddress | publicIpAdress | Owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678901 | i-0abcdef1234567890 | Test123 | t3a.micro | windows | stopped | ap-southeast-2a | 10.0.0.100 |  | test-user |
| 98765432109 | i-0987654321abcdefg | test345 | t2.nano | Linux | running | ap-southeast-2b | 10.0.0.200 | 99.99.99.100 | user@example.com |
| 98765432109 | i-abcdefghij01234899 | test987 | t2.nano | windows | running | ap-southeast-2b | 10.0.0.201 |  |  |

I tried a few things with no luck and would really appreciate if you can help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a clear text based sample of your data. Images are not OK

Comment: You added the text for one, but not the other. The second 'text' link links to the same image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Owner'] = df['Owner'].str.split('/').str[-1]
```

Demonstration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Owner': ['arn:aws:sts::12345678901:user/test-user']})
df['Owner'].str.split('/').str[-1]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @keramat, but it fails with the error

    >>> df['Owner'] = df['Owner'].str.split('/')[-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/darshan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py", line 385, in get_loc
    return self._range.index(new_key)
ValueError: -1 is not in range
The file does have owner column and both the rows in the column have strings with delimeter "/"

Comment: Sorry, edited the code.